# Programmatically set an observe block (instead of static object)?

Tags: polymer

Instead of:

Polymer({
      observe: {
        'key1': 'onDataChange',
        'key2': 'onDataChange'
      },

Can one programmatically execute an observer function for any data attribute data change (top-level)? I tried setting this.observe after creating an observe block object by looping over this.attributes, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that there's support for "wildcards" in the keys of the `observe` block, but you can specify a space-separated list of attributes that share the same data-changed observer function.

E.g.

```
observe: {
  'key1 key2': 'onDataChange'
}
```

You can see a real world example of it [in the `<google-youtube-video-wall>` element](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-youtube-video-wall/blob/master/google-youtube-video-wall.html#L670).

(I'm not exactly sure why it's [not documented](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#observeblock), though. I'll follow up on that.)

An alternative to using an `observe` block is to add a callback for the [`attributeChanged` element lifecycle event](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#lifecyclemethods), e.g.:

```
Polymer({
  // ...
  attributeChanged: function(attrName, oldVal, newVal) {
    console.log(attrName, 'old: ' + oldVal, 'new:', newVal);
  }
  // ...
});
```

Comment: In your example, you don't have quotation marks around onDataChange btw.

Comment: Thanks—I'm used to using anonymous functions for that use case. Fixed!

Comment: Yeah. So there's also the "attributeChanged" callback, which almost works as I'd hope - but it requires one use setAttribute unless you publish.. So I think this question is kind of just dead in the water.

Comment: Good point. I'll add attributeChanged to the answer just for the sake of completeness.